# Translation of "nobody wants to fight (with) him"

Tags: vocabulary

I have relatively simple question. I got introduced to the verb "싸우다" and I was curious for its usage in "wanting to fight".

```
The phrase I want to say: nobody wants to fight (with) him.

I came up with this: 아무도 그와 싸울래 않아

Naver gave me this:  아무도 그와 싸우고 싶어하지 않는다.
```

My main reasoning is that 싸울래 means "want to fight", but i'm not sure if that can only be used in the context of trying to pick a fight with someone or if it can be used as I have attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 아무도 그와 싸울래 않아

There are a couple of things that can be improved there -

- the (으)ㄹ래 construction isn't a general way of saying 'want'. It's specific to saying "I want to do something" (first person), or asking "Do you want to do something?" (second person). It's not really right for talking about things that nobody or anybody wants to do.
- The most common ways of negating a Korean verb are to put 안 before the verb, or use -지 않다 as a verb ending. However, (으)ㄹ래 is already a verb ending, so you can't use 지 않다. You could say 안 싸울래, meaning 'I don't want to fight'.

Comment: So if i was to say 너와 안싸울래, that means, i don't want to fight you, right? But if i was to say 아무도 그와 안 싸울래, it would make no sense because ㄹ래 is implying it HAS to be with me? In that case, what would be the normal informal way to say my original sentence of "nobody wants to fight him"?

Comment: @Kunsan yes, as a statement, ㄹ래 is talking about what *you* want. So 너와 안싸울래 means "i don't want to fight you". For  "nobody wants to fight him", your Naver translation is quite good.